# reactive forms pattern IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, internet-explorer

I have this form:

```
   this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
      weight: [weight, [Validators.pattern('^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')]],
      height: [height, [Validators.pattern('^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')]]
    });
```

With the following inputs:

```
      <input type="number" placeholder="Indtast din højde i cm" name="height" formControlName="height" class="form-control"/>
      <div *ngIf="form.get('height').dirty && form.get('height').invalid" class="error-text">
        No Letters
      </div>

     <input type="number" placeholder="Indtast din vægt i kg" name="weight" formControlName="weight" class="form-control"/>
      <div *ngIf="form.get('weight').dirty && form.get('weight').invalid" class="error-text">
        No Letters
      </div>
```

This works as intended on chrome however in IE I am able to write both numbers and characters without getting an error message.

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the pattern validation actually doesn't work in neither Chrome nor IE. I agree with Petr Averyanov's answer. You can also refer to [this thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27758) and [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#pattern_validation). In the doc, it says:

> `<input type="number">` elements do not support use of the pattern attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex pattern.

You can change the input type to `type="text"`, then it can work in both IE and Chrome.

Result in IE 11:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is invalid, patterns never worked in number inputs and does not work now (Just checked it in Chrome with ​input 'e').

You need either change input type to text or allow letters (Actually why not... 1e1 === 10 -- you can add validation for input to be a valid number)